# The name 'model' does not exist in the current context and The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've seen a few posts on both of these errors, and those who asked about it seemed to reach a solution by following the commentators' directions; however, after recreating the same solution, I get code that's more broken than before I started (the solution being to edit the Web.config files).

What's interesting here is that my MVC application has multiple tabs the user can click through, and they all work fine with the exception of one of them. This "Cranes" tab (click on it to view all the cranes in the database) is the only View which will generate this error. I've even gone into the View code for the other tabs and they all SAY they have the same error pre-runtime (red squiggles saying that 'Model' does not exist), but when I start the application, they all work fine except for Cranes.

What are some things I might look for that could cause this?

Pic of code in the View where I run into the problem:
[image]

Pic of code from another View where there is no error

(Again, it SAYS there's an error, but works fine @ runtime):

[image]

Comment: Just to check, you have a web.config file in both the root of your solution and another web.config file in your Views folder, right?

Comment: This is actually a pretty common Visual Studio bug. If you google "Visual Studio cshtml intellisense" you'll find a lot of people with the same problem, some with common causes.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid - yes, I have the Web.config files in both the main project as well as the Views folder\

Comment: @DPac - I'll take a look down that road and see what pops up, thanks

Comment: This occasionally pops up for me as well.  Often it is shortly after I open a solution.  It eventually goes away for me but I can't say why.

Comment: in the root web.config file.. under `<appsettings>` what is the `value` for the key `webpages:Version`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid It's running version 2.0.0.0 - this code has been around for at least a year now and I'm just maintaining it. The first solution I came across was to change all the API and MVC versions to 3 and 5 from 2 and 4 but that just started throwing runtime errors in the web.config file